# Calling another classes method with the object of the class

Tags: java, methods, interface, this, implementation

Class `A` implements interface `I` that requires method `doAction()`. If I call a method from class `A` **of** class `B`,  and pass "`this`"(class `A`) into that method, how can I call a method that lives in class `A` from the method in class `B`? For example:

```
class A implements I {
    public void start() {
        B.myMethod(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void doAction() {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

Class B {
    public void myMehtod(Class theClass) { //How would I accept 'this', and...
        theClass.doAction(); //How would I call the method?
    }
}
```

I am doing this for purposes of a custom library, without knowing the exact name of the class that extends `I`.

Comment: You have a typo in 'myMehtod'

Comment: Based on your end goal, you may find reading about the [Command Pattern](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/command-pattern.html) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very basic question about how interfaces work. I'd recommend trying to find a tutorial about them.

Anyway, all you have to do is declare a parameter with the interface as its type. You can invoke interface methods on variables of the interface type (or any sub interface or class that implements that interface).

```
Class B {
    public void myMethod(I theClass) {
        theClass.doAction();
    }
}
```